# How does Android File Storage Work?

Tags: android

I am working on a project that needs to store some .txt to android, and get it from the computer for other use. From what I read from the documentation, I know that there are two types of storage: 1 Internal, which is somewhere deep in the phone that is private to the app. 2 External, which includes the SD card and the Internal Storage of the phone. I want to store it to External->Internal, and I am using this line of code to do that:

`public String WalkDir =  android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Walks/";`

When I logged WalkDir, LogCat says "/storage/emulated/0", I stopped the app, checked with the adb shell, and there is no folder "0" but "legacy". I unplugged the phone and plugged it back in, the "Walks" folder is now in the root directory, and I don't need adb shell to access it.

So my question is, can you help explain how this system works? Why did "0" disappear? What is "legacy"? Why is the file in Internal Storage when I unplug&plug it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: No. There is internal, external and removable memory. The latter is a micro SD card. The first two are build into the device. Don't use adb to investigate. Use a file explorer app on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Those are what in Linux are called symlinks (like shortcuts in Windows) that various system apps in Android are using..

/storage, /sdcard are sym linked folders,that means when you open one of those, it redirects to the original(/data/media/0), as for the 0 is just a multi user feature implemented in android 4.2, but only enabled on tablet androids.
Why do this Sym-Link?: simple so it dosent break apps(not only file explorer type of app, but all apps).
Still dont get, why it would break?.Simple. android api have lots of ways to write/read files from folders, u can do manually,u can get the data path, u can get the sdcard path, etc,etc. so to not break that they just does these sym links, thats why in one app the storage contentents are listed on /sdcard but on others, is /storage, etc,etc. one example of an app that broke because of these changes to android is titanium backup, u need to change the internal storage on it, so it work.

2 mount points pointing to the same storage device and partition.
If you create something in one folder, it will show up in the other. Same applies for deleting stuff.
They do not take away more storage space, as it is only available once but shown twice.

You also don't need to worry about it in any way because file browsers normally set their default directory to one of these locations.

As far as i know, Google changed the mount points in Android 4.2 to /storage/emulated/0/ due to them switching to MTP and EXT4(?) for the sdcard. The other mount points are still there for compatibility.